# Can't connect to MySQL Database in phpBB

Tags: mysql, phpbb, mysql-connect

I am trying to connect to a MySQL database using the mysql_connect() command however I keep getting the error message:

Warning: mysql_connect() [function.mysql-connect]: [2002] A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not (trying to connect via tcp://ravenwolftest.db.4292619.hostedresource.com:3306) in C:\Data\GITA\Web Design\Projects\Ravenwolf\LoginTest.php on line 12

Warning: mysql_connect() [function.mysql-connect]: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond. in C:\Data\GITA\Web Design\Projects\Ravenwolf\LoginTest.php on line 12

I searched around in the phpBB folder and found in the config.php folder there was listed a host name, username, and password. I put those into the mysql_connect() line but get the same error. I am also using godaddy.com for web hosting in case that means anything. As for the code itself all I have is:

```
mysql_connect('ravenwolftest.db.4292619.hostedresource.com','ravenwolftest','password');
```

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it seems that either the other server is down or does not allow external connections to the database.
i would suggest that you enable external access in your godaddy control panel

Comment: I do remember not enabling some kind of remote access thing, however that was in the setup, do you have any idea where I could change that?

Comment: ok, I made a new database with remote access enabled and that fixed everything, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Do you control the machine `ravenwolftest.db.4292619.hostedresource.com`?  Is MySQL running on it?  If it's not your local machine, have you verified that MySQL is permitting connections from your machine?

Comment: I do not control that machine, however I set this up through godaddy.com, so I would assume that MySQL runs and will permit me.

Comment: Assume nothing, especially with low quality hosting providers like GoDaddy.  Ask their support techs if they permit outside MySQL connections.  The answer is very likely to be "no."